# hi i have problem in kali linys

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kali, dpkg

```
kali@kali:~$ sudo apt install tor
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  tor-geoipdb torsocks
Suggested packages:
  mixmaster torbrowser-launcher tor-arm apparmor-utils obfs4proxy
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  tor tor-geoipdb torsocks
0 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 0 to remove and 266 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/3,532 kB of archives.
After this operation, 14.9 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Selecting previously unselected package tor.
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
 files list file for package 'pci.ids' is missing final newline
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

Comment: What have you made before trying to install tor?

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem on Raspbian:

```
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:  files list file for
package 'init-system-helpers' is missing final newline E: Sub-process
/usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

This solved the problem for me:

```
sudo mv /var/lib/dpkg/info/init-system-helpers.* /tmp
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get install --reinstall init-system-helpers
```

Means moving the package information files somewhere else. Configuring unfinished packages and reinstalling the package which caused problems.